# using combo box to choose the name of file

Tags: c#, windows

- i have some sound files in folder and i need to open one of them using combo box to choose the name of it but i have a problem in the path configuration can anyone tell me what is the wrong here?

the combo box filled with static records.

- the error:

[image: > [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyCvH.jpg]

```
                if (radioButton1.Checked)
                {
                    UpdateLable upd = UpdateDataLable;
                    if (label1.InvokeRequired)
                        Invoke(upd, label1, "stop");
                    SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
                    player.SoundLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Alarm\'" + cb1.Text + "'.wav";
                    player.PlayLooping();
                }
```

Comment: Please add the error to your post instead of a link to an external source.

Comment: @RyanWilson I've done this but waiting for the edit to be accepted

Comment: @MidoSaeed While we are waiting on the edit, what is the error?

Comment: are you calling this method from thread ? or task ? or backgroundworker ?

Comment: @RyanWilson - its threading error , of accessing ui control , he must be calling method from other thread i am sure on tha t

Comment: @PranayRana Yep. Right as rain.

Comment: how to call it from another thread?

Comment: @Mido you are trying to accessing GUI from the external thread that's impossible. GUI can be accessed only from GUI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of code missing here specially how you are calling code you given in question, Based on Error message you must be calling method from other thread or task or background worker etc. or any other from that create threads.

To avoid this better you do call to method on UI thread itself.

or make use of [Control.BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx) - Executes the specified delegate asynchronously on the thread that the control's underlying handle was created on.

Comment: the code working good when i replace the the path to 1 file path without combo box

Comment: @MidoSaeed - that should work as you are not accessing combo box...real problem is thread